# tapestry apache error http 500 log

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, logging, tapestry

My project makes this error and I do not get whats wrong, here is error log from browser.
[log.txt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIdM4KQOtH8&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=21&feature=plpp_video)

---

I have no idea what is compatible, these libraries are imported

```
 .:
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr-runtime-3.1.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
chenillekit-core-1.3.2.jar
chenillekit-google-1.3.2.jar
chenillekit-hibernate-1.3.2.jar
chenillekit-image-1.3.2.jar
chenillekit-tapestry-1.3.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-io-1.3.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
CopyLibs
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
eclipselink
eclipselinkmodelgen
ejb3-persistence
geronimo-spec-jta-1.0-M1.jar
hibernate-c3p0-3.6.0.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-support
javaee-endorsed-api-6.0
javaee-endorsed-api-6.0-2
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
jsontools-core-1.5.jar
junit
junit-3.8.2.jar
junit_4
junit-4.5.jar
junit-4.5-src.jar
kaptcha-2.3.2.jar
libs
log4j-1.2.14.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
nblibraries-private.properties
nblibraries.properties
ognl-2.7.3.jar
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
Tap5
tapestry5-annotations-5.2.4.jar
tapestry-core-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-func-5.2.4.jar
tapestry-hibernate-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-hibernate-core-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-ioc-5.2.4.jar
tapestry-json-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-upload-5.2.4.jar
tapx-core-1.1-20110620.210912-27.jar
tapx-core-1.2-20110705.222421-4.jar
tapx-datefield-1.1-20110617.214353-17.jar
tapx-datefield-1.2-20110705.222544-4.jar

./CopyLibs:
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

./eclipselink:
eclipselink-2.2.0.jar
eclipselink-javax.persistence-2.0.jar

./eclipselinkmodelgen:
eclipselink-jpa-modelgen-2.2.0.jar

./ejb3-persistence:
ejb3-persistence.jar

./hibernate-support:
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate-tools.jar
javassist.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jta.jar

./javaee-endorsed-api-6.0:
javaee6-doc-api.zip
javax.annotation.jar
jaxb-api-osgi.jar
webservices-api-osgi.jar

./javaee-endorsed-api-6.0-2:
javaee6-doc-api.zip
javax.annotation.jar
jaxb-api-osgi.jar
webservices-api-osgi.jar

./junit:
junit-3.8.2-api.zip
junit-3.8.2.jar

./junit_4:
junit-4.5-api.zip
junit-4.5.jar
junit-4.5-src.jar

./Tap5:
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr-runtime-3.1.1.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
jta-1.0.1B.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
tapestry5-annotations-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-core-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-func-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-ioc-5.2.6.jar
tapestry-json-5.2.6.jar
tapx-core-1.1-20110620.210912-27.jar
tapx-core-1.2-20110705.222421-4.jar
tapx-datefield-1.1-20110617.214353-17.jar
tapx-datefield-1.2-20110705.222544-4.jar
```

everything looks normal exept for one thing I am trying to use hibernate inheritance with tapestry.

Code of parent class

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pz850.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

/**
 *
 * @author nikola
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "GRUPA")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grupa.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Grupa g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grupa.findByGrupaId", query = "SELECT g FROM Grupa g WHERE g.grupaId = :grupaId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grupa.findByGrupaNaziv", query = "SELECT g FROM Grupa g WHERE g.grupaNaziv = :grupaNaziv"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Grupa.findByGrupaBroj", query = "SELECT g FROM Grupa g WHERE g.grupaBroj = :grupaBroj")})
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Grupa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "GRUPA ID")
    private Integer grupaId;
    @Column(name = "GRUPA NAZIV")
    private String grupaNaziv;
    @Column(name = "GRUPA BROJ")
    private Integer grupaBroj;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Predmet predmet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Collection<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Grupa() {
    }

    public Grupa(Integer grupaId) {
        this.grupaId = grupaId;
    }

    public Integer getGrupaId() {
        return grupaId;
    }

    public void setGrupaId(Integer grupaId) {
        this.grupaId = grupaId;
    }

    public String getGrupaNaziv() {
        return grupaNaziv;
    }

    public void setGrupaNaziv(String grupaNaziv) {
        this.grupaNaziv = grupaNaziv;
    }

    public Integer getGrupaBroj() {
        return grupaBroj;
    }

    public void setGrupaBroj(Integer grupaBroj) {
        this.grupaBroj = grupaBroj;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (grupaId != null ? grupaId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Grupa)) {
            return false;
        }
        Grupa other = (Grupa) object;
        if ((this.grupaId == null && other.grupaId != null) || (this.grupaId != null && !this.grupaId.equals(other.grupaId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "pz850.entities.Grupa[ grupaId=" + grupaId + " ]";
    }
}
```

code of child class

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pz850.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;

/**
 *
 * @author nikola
 */
@Entity
public class InternetGrupa extends Grupa implements Serializable{
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @Column(name="VRSTA_STUDIRANJA")
    @Property
 private String vrstaStudija = "Internet";



    public InternetGrupa() {
    } public String getVrstaStudija() {
        return vrstaStudija;
    }

    public void setVrstaStudija(String vrstaStudija) {
        this.vrstaStudija = vrstaStudija;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final InternetGrupa other = (InternetGrupa) obj;
        if ((this.vrstaStudija == null) ? (other.vrstaStudija != null) : !this.vrstaStudija.equals(other.vrstaStudija)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.vrstaStudija != null ? this.vrstaStudija.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Internet{" + "vrstaStudija=" + vrstaStudija + '}';
    }
}
```

If it is a library which one should be removed?
Do you think this is parent child inheritance makes hibernate problem?
I think i have done it correctly as [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIdM4KQOtH8&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=21&feature=plpp_video) says

Comment: The key element in that stack trace is the IncompatibleClassChangeError. Do you have multiple versions of Hibernate on the classpath? Is the Hibernate version you are using compatible with the version of tapestry-hibernate you are using?

Comment: By the way, this is a bad question, consisting of little more than a stack trace in a paste bin, and giving no indication of what has been tried.

Answer (score 1):

As @Henning implied, there is conflict between your libraries. In this particular case, it's a tapestry-hibernate library that doesn't have it's true support in hibernate library( version which is not supported by the current tapestry-hibernate library ), so you should go to [DOCJAR](http://www.docjar.com) to see what true hibernate library( OR maybe even libraries, not sure what on how many of them depends tap-hibernate library ) is needed for your particular tapestry-hibernate library.

Comment: OK, this is good so far, checked dependencies and I can't find any deprecated library use, so now I deem it's probably you didn't setup Session with your hibernate db, even though your ValueEncoder service is trying to make a contact( ie you are dealing with db transactions of any kind somewhere ). So first thing you should do is to create a db with your sql file or from a command line, and then make hibernate property file in which you will link your entities and everything else to that db. Start your app and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is on the classpath twice, as 3.5 and as a nondescript 3.x (hibernate3.jar) via hibernate-support (what is that?). Fixing your classpath will help.